# Displaying another Activity after clicking a menu item

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I am writing my first Android app. I have three Activities: BaseballCardList, BaseballCardDetails, and FilterBaseballCards. BaseballCardList loads as the main Activity. It has a menu with two options to display one of the other two activities. BaseballCardDetails loads just fine. However, when I try to load FilterBaseballCards, I get a "Unfortunately, BBCT for Android has stopped." error message. I am running my app in the Android emulator. Here is the relavant code:

res/layout/card_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/card_list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

res/layout/filter_cards.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView android:text="@string/filter_by_label" />
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/filter_by">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/year"
                     android:text="@string/year_radio_button"
        />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/number"
                     android:text="@string/number_radio_button"
        />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/year_and_number"
                     android:text="@string/year_and_number_radio_button"
        />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/player_name"
                     android:text="@string/player_name_radio_button"
        />
    </RadioGroup>
    <Button android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:text="@string/ok_button"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:text="@string/cancel_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

BaseballCardList.java:

```
package bbct.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BaseballCardList extends Activity {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "BaseballCardList";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.card_list);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Starting BaseballCardDetails");

                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, BaseballCardDetails.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.filter:
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Starting FilterBaseballCards");

                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, FilterBaseballCards.class));
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

FilterBaseballCards.java:

```
package bbct.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FilterBaseballCards extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter_cards);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="bbct.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".BaseballCardList"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BaseballCardDetails" />
        <activity android:name=".FilterBaseballCards" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

BaseballCardDetails.java is nearly identical to FilterBaseballCards.java, so I won't post it.

Why am I getting this error message? More importantly, how do I go about tracking down the problem myself? I am using the Android command-line tools, not Eclipse. I started adding some logging messages, but I don't know how to view the logging output that might help me trace the source of the problem.

**Update:**

I changed the `setContentView()` in FilterBaseballCards to `setContentView(R.layout.card_details);` and the `card_details` view loads just fine. This narrows down the problem to my `filter_cards.xml` file.

**Another Update:**

I simplified `filter_cards.xml` down to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView android:text="@string/filter_by_label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and continue to get the same error as before.

Comment: what is the exception? can u post the manifest file?

Comment: It REALLY helps to use the Eclipse plugin. Then you can use the DDMS debugger that's part of the ADT plugin to step through your program and see EXACTLY where your error is occuring and what values all your variables have at the time it occurs.

Comment: @dor506 I don't see any exception or stack trace. I only get a dialog box in the emulator with the error message "Unfortunately, BBCT for Android has stopped." Can I pull up a stack trace from within the emulator? Also, I have added AndroidManifest.xml to my question.

Comment: Make sure in your `FilterBaseballCards` activity that you can set the view. If you can with lets say the `card_list` then the problem persists in your view.

Comment: @Nate That has been the most helpful hint so far. Updating my question...

Comment: @Code-Guru check my answer I think it has to do with your resources or the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
adb logcat
```

to view logging from command prompt

probably you have not added entries to manifest file for your new activities, for more on starting one activity from another look here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: I added AndroidManifest.xml to my question. As you can see, I include `<activity>` tags for all three of my Activities.

Comment: looks like it should work, you shold look into logcat for actual exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think your view is right mostly. Except I didn't like this line

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" //Here wrap_content? Shouldn't it be fill_parent?
              android:orientation="vertical"               
>
```

Other than that your resources might be messed up (not accessing the right ones / names are wrong) @string/name Or @+id/name

EDIT:

I also noticed you don't assign an ID to the `TextView` probably should do that ;)

Comment: If I have `@+id/year` for widgets in both filter_cards.xml and card_details.xml views, could that possibly cause the error I am seeing? Why doesn't this name-clash cause a compiler error?

Comment: Yes it will because the '+' creates a new ID in R for that resource. You can by my knowledge do @id/year but idk if you want to do this.

Comment: All the examples I have seen don't assign IDs to `TextView` widgets. Since one typically doesn't need to access them in Java code, I can understand why. Analogously in my Swing programming, I rarely keep `JLabel` references.

Comment: Ah if you don't need them I guess its fine. Did you try the `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`?

Comment: Okay, that *might* be the problem. I have a `EditText` in card_details.xml and a `RadioButton` in filter_cards.xml both with `@+id/year`.

Comment: Working on that right now...waiting for emulator to load and code to compile...oh look it's finished finally...

Comment: I can see that being a problem. The creation of the same ID the app isn't going to like that.

Comment: Hrmm...fill_parent doesn't fix the problem...on to more trouble-shooting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally tracked down the problem and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to add the activies you are starting to the manifest.

More on Intent Filters: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: I added AndroidManifest.xml to my question. As you can see, I include `<activity>` tags for all three of my Activities.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nate noted, and I verified, the problem was in the view for my FilterBaseballCards activity. In particular, I modified the `filter_cards.xml` layout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_by_label" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I added `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes to the `TextView` tag. After doing this, the app compiles and runs correctly in the Android emulator.

Comment: Haha doh I hate those bugs, can never find them

Comment: @Nate You at least pointed me in the right direction to track them down. I learned my lesson to add stuff by baby steps while I learn Android programming. Part of my problem was adding too much code between compiling and testing.

Comment: Well its ok to add lots of code as long as you understand it. When your learning it its a lot harder to just code.

Comment: @Nate Yah, and I thought I understood what I was doing...apparently not.