# Menu click displays the wrong activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have created three Activities for an Android app: BaseballCardsList, BaseballCardsDetails, and FilterBaseballCards. BaseballCardsList is the main activity which loads when my app is launched. It has a menu which then displays one of the other two activities. Now when I just had BaseballCardsList and BaseballCardsDetails, everything seemed to be working correctly. But as I added FilterBaseballCards, I keep running into problems. I already figured out [one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557073/displaying-another-activity-after-clicking-a-menu-item) where I left out `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes. My current problem is that changes to my XML layout files for BaseballCardsDetails or FilterBaseballCards cause a menu click to load the wrong Activity or to not load any Activity at all (the app remains on BaseballCardsList).

At the moment, I have the following in filter_cards.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/filter_by_label" 
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This compiles and runs as I expect. When I add

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel_button"
    />
```

at the end of the LinearLayout, clicking on the menu to load BaseballCardDetails loads the widgets that should be in FilterBaseballCards and clicking on the menu to load FilterBaseballCards does nothing.

I'm new to Android programming and am getting quite frustrated with this. I thought I understood how everything works from the reading I've done but apparently not. I don't know why adding a Button widget causes a seemingly unrelated problem. And I don't know how to track down what the real problem is. Where do I look to figure this out? If I need to post more code, I will be glad to do so. My last question ended up so long with all the code, though, so I didn't want to inundate everyone with so much code in my new question.

**FilterBaseballCards.java**

```
package bbct.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FilterBaseballCards extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter_cards);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may happen in the FilterBaseballCards activity, can you post the log as well as the FilterBaseballCards code.

Comment: @jaredzhang I have posted FilterBaseballCards.java, which is *very* bare bones. As for the log, `adb logcat` gives me over 650 lines. I'm not sure how to filter out the useful parts from that.

Comment: it seems no problem with your activity, how about the error log from logcat, actually, that's more important

Comment: @jaredzhang Is `logcat` different from `adb logcat`?

Comment: @jaredzhang p.s. I'm using the command-line tools, not Eclipse

Comment: so you are sure before you added the cancel button it works? did you add the string you refer here '            android:text="@string/cancel_button"
', if you did, try to clean your code and run again.

Comment: @jaredzhang Running `ant clean` and then `ant debug install` seems to fix the problem. :: scratches head ::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my speculation about what happens when you change resources and ids in the XML files in your Android project:

The R class generated by aapt contains a bunch of `static final ints`. When you compile source files that reference these, the value is hardcoded into the resulting .class file. Now when you change a resource or id and the R class is regenerated, the values of the `static final ints` are regenerated. It is possible that the value that is hardcoded in your compiled .class file refers to a different resource.

I'm too tired to test if this is correct. So if anyone can confirm my guess, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

i Hope  that you have Declared your class file in your `Manifest`

```
    <activity android:name=".Your Claass Name">
```

Comment: Yes I have. Thanks for checking ;-)